# Dynamic CRM contacts are appearing in Xdb.Collection sql table but not appearing in experience profile

Tags: xdb, xconnect, dynamics-crm-module

When I sync `CRM` contacts to Sitecore by running `Dynamics Contacts to xConnect Sync` pipeline batch, I can see contacts in `Xdb.Collection` SQL table, but not in Sitecore `Experince Profile`.

Is this because contacts don't have interactions? What could be the possible fix?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a normal behavior. Your contacts are anonymous (without interactions)  and anonymous contact are not indexed OOTB. 
To change the contact to be indexed you need to change in 2 places in xconnect:

1. Open the xConnect Search Indexer's sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml configuration file. In a default on-premise deployment, the full path is C:\path\to\xconnect\root\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Config\Sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml
2. Set IndexAnonymousContactData to true as shown:

> `<Settings>`

```
     <Sitecore>
        <XConnect>
     <!-- SearchIndexer role requires Collection and CollectionSearch role services -->
       <SearchIndexer>
            <Services>
           <IndexerSettings>
                <Type>Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexerSettings,
 Sitecore.Xdb.Collection</Type>
                 <LifeTime>Singleton</LifeTime>
                 <Options>
                 <IndexPIISensitiveData>false</IndexPIISensitiveData>
                 <IndexAnonymousContactData>false</IndexAnonymousContactData>
                 </Options>
             </IndexerSettings>
             <IIndexer>
                 <Type>Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.DecoratedIndexer,
 Sitecore.Xdb.Collection</Type>
                 <As>Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IIndexer, Sitecore.Xdb.Collection</As>
                 <LifeTime>Singleton</LifeTime>
             </IIndexer>
             <IIndexRebuildFlow>
                 <Type>Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexRebuildFlow,
 Sitecore.Xdb.Collection</Type>
                 <As>Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IIndexRebuildFlow,
 Sitecore.Xdb.Collection</As>
                 <LifeTime>Singleton</LifeTime>
                 <Options>
                 <IncomingDataLagOnCompletion>0.00:00:05</IncomingDataLagOnCompletion>
                 <!--Enable ParallelizationDegree setting to override default value which is (processorCount*4)-->
                 <!--<ParallelizationDegree>16</ParallelizationDegree>-->
                 <BatchSize>1000</BatchSize>
                 </Options>
             </IIndexRebuildFlow>
             </Services>
         </SearchIndexer>
         </XConnect>
       </Sitecore>
     </Settings>
```

3. Rebuild the xDB search index.

More information you can find here : https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts.html

Comment: Thanks Vlad but in my case I have already set IndexAnonymousContactData to true but still contacts are not appearing in experience profile.

Comment: can you check if you have data in xdb index?

Comment: I can see the data in xdb index but seems that only contains known contacts (created in sitecore) but don't have contacts which have come from dynamic crm, although crm contacts are synced in xdb (sql table). fyi: its sitecore 9.02

Comment: are you doing on your local machine ?

Comment: yes i am doing on local machine

Comment: Vlad its updating xdb index as well, only issue is contacts are not appearing in experience profile.